# Move Powershell File Structure if no File exists in Target Directory

Tags: file, powershell

I want to Move a File Strucuture, unpacked by .zip Files to a Target Directory.

Extracting ZIP works, The Moving of the files too.

But there are several cases that the Target Directory already contains a file with the same name as the file-structure-to-copy.

Maybe i want to copy all Files from /temp/ to /target/

There is a File /temp/new/2/test.txt and it already exists in /target/new/2/test.txt

=> In this case, I don't want to copy any files from the Temp Folder to the Target folder.

How do I realize this with powershell?

The way, I am moving my files now is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $unzipDir -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $targetDir
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out the files where the target path would already exist.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $unzipDir -Recurse |
Where { -not Test-Path (Join-Path $targetDir $_) } |
Move-Item -Destination $targetDir
```

- Inside the `Where` body, the `$_` refers to the current file.
- `Join-Path` deals with building a valid path from two parts.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Was not 100 % of that what I wanted, but I can Filter, which Files exist and if File Exists, I can break up the Moving of the Files. Thank you !

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood you there (overlooked the "any"). Good you could put it to use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(-not (Test-Path "./target/new/2/test.txt")){
    Get-ChildItem -Path $unzipDir -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $targetDir
}
```